# Uninstalling ArcGIS10 License Manager?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-license-manager

I recently uninstalled the ArcGIS 10 from my computer, the software got uninstalled , but I am unable to uninstall the License manager. It is giving me an error  "you don't have sufficient access to uninstall ArcGIS license manager 10"..and I am logged in as Admin.

Due to this problem I am not able to install the ArcGIS 10.1.

Comment: How are you uninstalling ArcGIS license manager ? from the control panel?

Comment: Have you tried stopping the service manually first before running the uninstall?

Comment: Hey AR ..thanks for the reply yes I am using control panel...@Jamie-I checked MSconfig..therez no service running(actually nothing related to ArcGIS is being shown over there)

Comment: I can still see the ArcGIS License manager in the uninstall programs list in control panel.

Comment: There might be an orphan entry in Windows Registry. Use a tool like Iolo's System Mechanic to fix orphan entried. The tool also has a specific utility to clean up incorrect Add/Remove entries...

Comment: I recommend to use CCleaner software for this uninstall

Answer (score 1):

If you are still stuck on this one then I recommend that you contact your [local Esri Support](http://support.esri.com/en/) who are likely to be encountering installation and license manager problems more frequently than most of us here.

Answer (score 0):

I personally recommend Revo Uninstaller. It removes all left overs. Also try to do virus scan and chech harddisk for error with Windows tools, it must solve te problem.